# Set PermSize for Tomcat Service

Tags: java, tomcat

This is the error I get when I run Tomcat Windows Service with Java Options -`XX:MaxPermSize128m` :

```
[2012-12-09 18:30:55] [395  javajni.c] [error] CreateJavaVM Failed
[2012-12-09 18:30:55] [1000 prunsrv.c] [error] Failed initializing java C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin\bootstrap.jar
[2012-12-09 18:30:55] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 2
```

Wherein, if the MaxPermSize is not set, Tomcat boots properly.

Comment: it must be: `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` not `-XX:MaxPermSize128m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the values in the `CATALINA_OPTS` option defined in the Tomcat Catalina start file. To increase the PermGen memory change the value of the MaxPermSize variable, otherwise change the value of the Xmx variable. For the Tomcat installed with the WebRatio tool the CATALINA_OPTS option is already present and you only have to change the variables values. Otherwise you have to add the declaration at the top of the file.

> In Windows Operating System you have to open the "Catalina.bat" file
>   placed in the "bin" directory. You have to apply the changes to this
>   line.
>
> ```
>   set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m
> ```